NodeJs SplunkSDK Get Api getting 500 Internal server error before the actual response received
I am new to Node js. I am using NodeJS pm2 and SplunkSDK@1.12.1. Requirement is to get splunk data as a response.
module.exports.executeSearch = function (query, params, cb) {        
        splunkService.oneshotSearch(query, params, function (err, results) {
        console.log("Query is : "+query);
        cb(err, results);
  });
};

And from the below code I am calling above method,
SplunkQuery.executeSearch(splunkSearch, splunkParams, function (err, results) {  
   if (err) {
      if (err.data && err.data.messages) {
        Log.error(err.data.messages);
      }
      var error = Boom.badRequest();
      error.reformat();
      error.output.payload = Response.buildResponse(Errors.ERROR_RECORD_RETRIEVAL_FAILURE, []);
      // return reply(error);
      throw err;
    }
    var events = [];
    var rawRowIndex = results.fields.indexOf('_raw');
    if (results.rows.length == 0 && request.query.id) {
      var error = Boom.badRequest();
      error.reformat();
      error.output.payload = Response.buildResponse(Errors.ERROR_INVALID_ID_PARAM, []);
      return h.response(error);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
      var splunkRecord = results.rows[i];
      Log.info("splunkRecord"+splunkRecord);
      if (splunkRecord && splunkRecord[rawRowIndex]) {
        var rawRecord = splunkRecord[rawRowIndex];        
    events.push(Util.splunkRecordToEvent(JSON.parse(rawRecord.replace(/\nValue of UseDynamoDB = True/g, ''))));
       }
    }
   Log.info("end splunck sear");
   Log.info('Splunk search completed, events count:'+events.length);
   h.response(Response.buildResponse(0, events));
  });

Below is the code from where I am calling api
module.exports = [
{
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/cmiapi/getrecord',
    handler: GetRecordRoutes.getRecord
}

Whenever I called my get api I am getting 500 internal server error on postman or through curl first. And then I can see the search result or response in console with the events count as 32.
How to get the events as a response. Please suggest. Thank you
Tried with various way to get response like h or reply or async etc but it still the same.

Explain the error or share the error

'Debug: internal, implementation, error
{"isBoom":true,"isServer":true,"data":null,"output":{"statusCode":500,"payload":{"statusCode":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"An internal server error occurred"},"headers":{}},"isDeveloperError":true}'
